# Generate a random string value for each

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I am fetching "Key" and "Value" from the DB and for each I want to insert a random string in value field.

Problem is that every "Value" field gets the same random string (same random value).
How can they get random string, separately, each one different?

```
foreach (var fields in formFields)
                {
                    FieldValues.Add(new FieldValues
                    {
                        Key = item.Key,
                        Value = RandomString(10,true)
                    });
                }


public string RandomString(int size, bool lowerCase)
        {
            StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
            Random random = new Random();
            char ch;
            for (int i = 0; i < size; i++)
            {
                ch = Convert.ToChar(Convert.ToInt32(Math.Floor(26 * random.NextDouble() + 65)));
                builder.Append(ch);
            }
            if (lowerCase)
                return builder.ToString().ToLower();
            return builder.ToString();
        }
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/767999/random-number-generator-only-generating-one-random-number

Comment: @Fubo, it is copy/paste from the another page.

Comment: `System.Guid.NewGuid().ToString("N").ToUpper();` will create a nice random string.

Comment: in one line `return string.Concat(Enumerable.Range(0, size).Select(x => (char)((lowerCase ? 'a' : 'A') + random.Next(26))));`

Comment: Yes but it is still giving same string to all values.

Comment: as the duplicate mark says, the issue is at `Random random = new Random();`